# select case when not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I'm trying to understand how this works but can't figure it out yet.

I have made this simple uery to test the case-when-then-end clause...

```
  SELECT case when quantity > 3
              then count(*) end the_count_a,
         case when quantity <= 3
              then count(*) end the_count_b
    FROM STOCK
```

my stock table has 30 items with different quantities, only 10 items have quantity over 3 but this is always returning 30.... WHY?
I think it should be returning two columns with values: 10 and 20

Any help will be appreciated!
Thx,
Leo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `count(*)` means the count of all records (in the current group), regardless of where it is placed.  If you want to count records that match a condition, you need to invert your case statement:

```
select count(case when quantity > 3 then 1 end) the_count_a,
       count(case when quantity <= 3 then 1 end) the_count_b
  from stock
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I wrote it as I would in an oracle db... It works!!! Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
       count(case when quantity > 3 then 1 else null end) end the_count_a,
       count(case when quantity <= 3 then 1 else null end) end the_count_b
FROM STOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate function `COUNT()` in absense of a `GROUP BY` will return all rows in the table which have not been filtered by a `WHERE` clause.  In your case, what you actually need are two subselects or a `UNION`, depending if you want columns or rows back:

```
/* Return columns with subselects */
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STOCK WHERE quantity > 3) AS the_count_a
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STOCK WHERE quantity <= 3) AS the_count_b
```

MySQL is lenient about the presence of a `FROM` clause, so it can be omitted from the outer query.

```
/* Return rows instead of columns with UNION */
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS the_count,
  'the_count_a'
FROM STOCK WHERE quantity > 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS the_count,
  'the_count_b'
FROM STOCK WHERE quantity <= 30
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for the quick answer!